# How do I disable UserAssist on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, process-monitor

My team runs a performance lab where we run continuous integration tests of our software on Windows 10. We noticed that `explorer.exe` occasionally starts to use a full core's worth of CPU for long periods of time. By using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), I found that `explorer.exe` was frequently accessing a specific registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\{CEBFF5CD-ACE2-4F4F-9178-9926F41749EA}`.

This registry key apparently helps UserAssist maintain "a list of applications, files, links, and other objects that have been accessed" ([source](https://windowsexplored.com/2012/02/06/a-quick-glance-at-the-userassist-key-in-windows/)).

When I open the `UserAssist\CEBFF5CD-...` key in regedit and click on the "Count" subfield, regedit freezes.

[image: Regedit freezes clicking registry key]

When I delete the entire `UserAssist\CEBFF5CD-...` key, I immediately see `explorer.exe`'s CPU usage drop from a full core to <1%.

I want to disable UserAssist to prevent it from interfering with performance tests, but am having trouble doing so. So far I've tried:

- [This website's suggestion](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/userassist/) of creating a `UserAssist\Settings` key with a DWORD value named `NoLog` under it with value `1`, then restarting `explorer.exe`.
- [This website's suggestion](https://windowsexplored.com/2012/02/06/a-quick-glance-at-the-userassist-key-in-windows/) to disable both "Privacy" options when under the start menu settings. (I had to alter these instructions slightly for Windows 10.) I also restarted `explorer.exe` after this.

I continued to see accesses to this registry key and high CPU use of `explorer.exe` after each of these attempted fixes.

**How can I disable UserAssist on Windows 10 to stop UserAssist from affecting my performance tests?**

Comment: Does UserAssist registry key reappear after deleting that key and rebooting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: after getting in touch with Microsoft, here's what worked.

Disabling UserAssist requires two steps:

1. Set two registry keys, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Start_TrackProgs` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Start_TrackEnabled`, both to zero in order to signal that we want UserAssist disabled.
2. Clear your registry subtrees that look like `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\<hash>`.

Comment: Did not work, I still see entries below `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\Explorer\UserAssist\` two minutes after performing the above and restarting explorer

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentvers ion\Explorer\Userassist`. You should see two subkeys called Count, delete both these keys. Now right-click the UserAssist key and create a new key named `Settings`. In this key create a DWORD value named `NoLog`, set the value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "Let Windows Track..." Does Not Work. Glary reports a ton of 'User Assist'privacy infringes and removes them until next time I restart the PC. I use Bitdefender to secure Win10 continual privacy infringements and it works well, but, I have a more direct and consistent method to knock-out user assist and other M10 nonsense On Start Ups. I use a simple little prg called "Tiny Wall". I have been using it for about ten years and set-up tight it stops all. However, be careful as you must disable TW when performing a W10 update as W10 will catch it and do a total work around and begin auto updates again.

Comment: This seems to be a comment to another answer